# how to input in the debug window while debugging Xcode 4 iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

How can I input data with getchar() or scanf() by typing into the debugger window (where printf output goes to) while debugging an iPhone app in Xcode 4?

I want to be able to quickly input control parameters just whil debugging.
(I'll add sliders later.)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call methods from the console, so you could change mutable objects, like

```
[myDictionary setObject:@"some value" forKey:@"key"]
```